# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module 123

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm building a single app with reactjs. but i can use import statement outside module
[image]

please solve me this problem. Thanks all

Comment: your question is not clear can you elaborate a little more?
what is exactly your app problem?

Comment: Make sure your script tag has the `type="module"` attribute (i.e. `<script src="app.js" type="module"></script>`).